# Display arrow indicator if list is scrollable

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have an horizontal SingleChildScrollView widget with variable amount of different buttons. I want to display button with right arrow only when there is too much buttons to show all on screen. I want to avoid situation when someone could dont know about more buttons hidden behind right edge of the screen.

How to achieve this?

```
Container(
 height: iconsBarHeight,
 color: Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor,
 padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16, 16, 8, 0),
 child: SingleChildScrollView(
  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
  child: Row(
   crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
   children: [
    Button2(),
    Button4(),
    Button1(),
    Button6(),
    Button7(),
    Button3(),
    Button2(),
   ],
  ),
 ),
);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can add ScrollControlller to SingleChildScrollView, and get the max extent of it. If max extent is greater than width of screen, then show the button.

```
scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent
```

Comment: `position.extentAfter` is better for this, because it already computes how much "unseen" is "after" the scroll.  That way, you don't have to think about the width of the screen... it has already done the job.